# What are the specific features of TY-90?

Tags: helicopter, missiles, missile-lock, china

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TY-90) about the TY-90 anti-helicopter missile mentions that China developed the TY-90 specifically as a helicopter-based anti-helicopter missile. This differs from the solution adopted elswhere, namely adapting MANPAD missile for use on helicopters.

While most articles are prolific on the feature that make the missile a anti-helicopter missile (all aspects, dual UV/IR, warhead...) I can't find information on what are the features that make it specifically suited for use in helicopters?

I'm troubled because my understanding is that any fire-and-forget missile could be used on any platform (if size and weight is ok). So why do the Chinese need a purpose-built missile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TY-90 is considerably larger than a MANPADS - 1.9m long and nearly 25 kg in weight.

MANPADS are restricted by human size and strength to about 15 kg for the missile.

A larger missile translates into more kinematic performance and a larger warhead, which allow more range and better kill probability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry that th equestion is closed